# Java Regex - Not coloring all matching word in JTextPane

Tags: java, regex, jtextpane

I want coloring all word that matching with commment

```
public WarnaText(JTextPane source) throws BadLocationException
{
    source.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    Matcher komen=Pattern.compile("//.+").matcher(source.getText());
    while(komen.find())
    {
        String getkomen=komen.group();
        StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
        AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.RED);
        aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.FontFamily, "Concolas");

        int start = source.getText().indexOf(getkomen);
        source.select(start,start + getkomen.length());

        source.setCharacterAttributes(aset, false);
    }
}
```

but, it some words are not colored at JTextPane which contains many comments

Comment: Why are you doing `getkomen=komen.group()` + `indexOf(getkomen)` when `komen.start()` will give it to you directly? Just use `source.select(komen.start(), komen.end())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code retrieve the comment text (`getkomen=komen.group()`), then searches for the *first* instance of that text (`...indexOf(getkomen)`). If you have multiple identical comments, only the first one will be colored.

The [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) will give you the position of the found text using [`start()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#start%28%29) and [`end()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#end%28%29). You should just use those.

```
Matcher komen=Pattern.compile("//.+").matcher(source.getText());
while(komen.find())
{
    StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
    AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.RED);
    aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.FontFamily, "Concolas");

    source.select(komen.start(), komen.end());

    source.setCharacterAttributes(aset, false);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can change from `source.select(start, start+getkomen.length)` to `source.select(komen.start(),komen.end())`

```
public WarnaText(JTextPane source) throws BadLocationException
{
    source.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    Matcher komen=Pattern.compile("(/\\*([^\\*]|(\\*(?!/))+)*+\\*+/)|(\\/\\/.+)").matcher(source.getText());
    while(komen.find())
    {
        StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
        AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.RED);

        aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.FontFamily, "Concolas");

        source.select(komen.start(),komen.end());

        source.setCharacterAttributes(aset, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice copy of my comment, then changing the regex without saying why or how it's supposed to be better. -1