# Java regex - Not Coloring on target

Tags: java, regex, colors

My Question Based from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649149/java-regex-not-coloring-all-matching-word-in-jtextpane/)

I got an answer :

```
Matcher komen=Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(source.getText());
while(komen.find())
{
    StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
    AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Background, randomColor);
    aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.FontFamily, "Concolas");

    source.select(komen.start(), komen.end());

    source.setCharacterAttributes(aset, false);
}
```

but, it's not coloring on target.

for example, here my pattern.

```
1. Pattern.compile("package").matcher(paket.group());
2. String getPack=Pattern.compile("(package\\s+)|(\\/\\/.*)|(;)").matcher(paket.group()).replaceAll("");
   Pattern.compile(getPack.replaceAll("\\s", "")).matcher(paket.group());
3. Pattern.compile("import").matcher(impor.group());
4. Pattern.compile("pustaka").matcher(impor.group());
5. String getPack=Pattern.compile("(import\\s+)|([\\w$*]+\\s*;)|(\\/\\/.*)|(\\s)").matcher(impor.group()).replaceAll("");
   Matcher getPackage=Pattern.compile(getPack.replaceAll("\\.$", "")).matcher(impor.group());
```

here my result :

[image: error]

Comment: If my memory serves me correctly, I don't believe you need to escape the forward slash

Comment: Are u know why not correctly ?